# jQuery equivalent of Ruby any?

Tags: jquery, code-formatting

So i'm looking for a concise way to determine if an array of objects returned from a selector have text.

My setup here is pretty basic, I've got a table and I'd like to determine if in a specified column I actually have data.  I initially thought the .is() method would be my answer, but I just couldn't get it to return anything but false:

```
$('.draft-date').is(function() { return ($(this).text() === ""); }); // <-- return false

$('.draft-date').is(function() { return ($(this).text() != ""); }); // <-- return false, but based on test data should return true
```

Now, am I misunderstanding the .is() method?  Is my code broken?

I've got a work around using .map and .inArray():

```
$.inArray(true, $.map($('.draft-date'), function(n, i) { return ($(n).text() != "");} ))
```

But I honestly don't like it much.  It's fugly.

Help me beautify my garden StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you want to know if all items in the collection have text, any item has text or no items have text?

Comment: `$('.draft-date').is(function() { return ($(this).text() === ""); })` works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dtK7y/.  It returns `true` if any item in the collection has no text and `false` if all items in the collection have text.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle example.  It turns out the version I'm working with, 1.5.2, behaves badly.  Take these upvotes for your trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest solution is to use the `text` method on the whole selection, because that returns all the elements' text data.

```
if ($('.draft-date').text() === '') {
    // all elements have no text
}
```

If any elements have text, that text will be returned.

<s>This is because `is` will only work on the first element in a set of elements. Otherwise, how would it know which result you wanted?</s>

Comment: Sweet baby jesus, I (obviously) had no clue .text() worked like that.  Consider yourself marked as answer in t-minus 8.

Comment: Your comment about .is() only working on the first element is not correct.  It runs the function against all elements until it finds one that returns true.  It returns true if any element tests as true and false if all elements test as false.  See [doc](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for details.

Comment: Additionally, I do believe you're mistaken about how 'is' works though, check out the jfiddle example in the question comments jfriend00 made.  It's clear that the 'is' tests against all elements.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm obliged for the correction. `is` is more powerful than I thought it was: good stuff.